# Excel VBA Charts -> range select using "Cells" in within Charts

Tags: excel, charts, runtime-error, office-2007, vba

I'm trying to modify an existing VBA code (Excel) which makes Chart graphs, and make it more flexible.

I know that the following pieces of code do basically the same thing:

```
Range(Cells(12, 2), Cells(15, 2)).Select
```

is more or less identical to:

```
Range("B12:B15").Select
```

My goal was to have a Graph, which is representing the flexible count of rows.

So I have changed the existing code:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Log-Data").Range("B12:B200"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

to

```
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row    
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Log-Data").Range(Cells(12, 2), Cells(LastRow, 2)), PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

Now, whenever I execute the code, I receive:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

The `LastRow` variable is not the problem: I have the same result if I replace it with 200.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Peter

Comment: Whenver you use `sheetname.Range(Cells(a,b), Cells(a2,b2))` you should always qualify each `Cells()` with the sheet reference: otherwise, `Cells()` will always refer to the ActiveSheet, which may not be what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Worksheets("Log-Data").Activate

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row    
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Log-Data").Range(Cells(12, 2), Cells(LastRow, 2)), PlotBy:=xlColumns

Worksheets("NAME_CHEET_CHART").Activate
```

Answer (score -1):

`LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row`

and

`LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`

are the same.

As far as the actual error goes, it looks as if you have no active chart object when the code is run. So `ActiveChart.` returns an object error.

Try this:

```
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Log-Data").Range(Cells(12, 2), Cells(LastRow, 2)), PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried the following and it works (adding a period before Cells word)

```
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

With Sheets("Log-Data")
Set Myrange = .Range(.Cells(12, 2), .Cells(LastRow, 2))
End With

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Myrange, PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

Answer (score -3):

**Try below and let me know**

```
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

With Sheets("Log-Data")
Set Myrange = .Range(Cells(12, 2), Cells(LastRow, 2))
End With

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Myrange, PlotBy:=xlColumns
```